# Charcter Validation In Ext js3.4

Tags: extjs3

I want to check validation for textfield in Ext js3.4...Validation condition is first 5 Character must be "ROLE_"...How would I check them...I also trying for getting value on keypress event through getKey method ..But I got only ASCII value ..how would I convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried keydown keyup events in listeners, in those events you will directly get the value using the id of the text field... here you go for a sample code

```
xtype:'textfield'
fieldLabel: 'First Name',
name: 'first',
allowBlank:false,
id:'name',
listeners:
 keyup:function(this,e){
var desiredname= Ext.getCmp('name').value;
if(desiredname.length==5)
{
             //YOUR CODE :)
}

}
```

Hope this helps you...